# Acumatica - How to use Existing DACs that have no database fields

Tags: c#, acumatica

I need to check the current balance on a customer.

According to the Inspector, it is using DAC CustomerBalanceSummary
[image: CustomerBalanceSummary]

This DAC has no datafields associate with it
[image: No Datafields]

How can I get this DAC's values in an extension using BQL?

EDIT:
Can I trigger the calculations via an API call and get the values from Cache?

Or, can I see how it comes up with its calculations? I want the Balance field that is seen in the Customer screen.

I see the ARBalances DAC, and can get it:

```
  ARBalances balance = PXSelectReadonly<ARBalances,
                    Where<ARBalances.customerID, Equal<Required<ARBalances.customerID>>>>
                    .Select(Base, currentCustomer.BAccountID);
```

However, I do not think ARBalances.CurrentBalance is the same value I see in CustomerBalanceSummary.

Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot. This value is calculated on the fly and is not stored in the database.

Comment: That is sad news. I made an edit above, is there a way to do what I ask in the edit?

Comment: You might be able to export the field via the page API